# Sweet.js: macro that targets variables before the tokens?

Tags: javascript, macros, sweet.js

One of the items on my TODO list is creating a fun coding language that 'compiles' to JavaScript. I would like to try out [Sweet.js](http://sweetjs.org/) for this, but I'm wondering if it is possible to write a rule that targets keywords that are **before** the rule?

As an example, let's say you'd want to create a Yoda-styled JavaScript. A source line could look like this:

```
six var is;
```

Would be mapped to

```
var six;
```

Is this possible using Sweet.js?

Comment: You can do that if you replace `var` with some other word, but not using `var` -- don't know why that's the case.

Comment: Could you post an example of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, you'll want to use [infix](http://sweetjs.org/doc/main/sweet.html#infix-macros) macros:

```
let var = macro {
    rule infix { $x:ident | is } => {
        var $x;
    }
}

six var is
```

If you wanted `is` to be the macro instead of `var` the obvious thing would be:

```
let is = macro {
    rule infix { $x:ident var | } => {
        var $x;
    }
}
```

But this doesn't actually work. The reason it doesn't work is that `var` is...special. Basically, since `var` creates a new binder, macros do not get expanded in the identifier positions of `var`. So when the expander sees `var is` it tries to create a new bound variable called `is` instead of expanding the `is` macro.

Using the infix `var` macro should work for you though.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about the infix operators!